# Python get whole hour values between 2 datetime objects

Tags: python, datetime

I have 2 datetime values: 'start' and end'. I'd like to return a list of all the datetimes that fall exactly on the hour between the two (inclusive).

For example 'start' is 09:30 and 'end' is 14:00 (same day). The values I'd like returned are 10:00, 11:00, 12:00, 13:00, 14:00.

I guess what you would do is get the next whole hour after 'start', add it to a blank list, then create a loop that adds and hours, tests if it's less than (or equal to) 'end' and append it to the list if true.

What I can't figure out is how to get the nearest whole hour to the start datetime.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest would be to replace the minutes and seconds of the start time with zero and then add one hour.

You will need a special case if the start time is exactly on the hour and you wish to include it

eg

```
>>> from datetime import datetime, timedelta
>>> start_time = datetime.now()
>>> start_time
datetime.datetime(2011, 5, 18, 20, 38, 55, 546000)
>>> first = start_time.replace(minute=0, second=0, microsecond=0)+timedelta(hours=1)
>>> first
datetime.datetime(2011, 5, 18, 21, 0)
>>>
```

Comment: You could handle the special case of the start time being exactly on the hour by subtracting a microsecond.

Comment: @Sven, you could do something like that, but the OP didn't specify whether the start time should be included if it is exactly on the hour, so the special case may not even be needed

Comment: Start time should be included if it's exactly on the hour :) This is working great for me. Thanks also Sven, that tip saved a few lines of code

Answer (score 1):

The best way to do that is using timedelta.

```
>>> from datetime import datetime, timedelta
>>> start = datetime.now()
>>> if start.minute >= 30:
...     start.replace(minute=0)+timedelta(hours=1)
... else:
...     start.replace(minute=0)
```