# C# get whole hour values between 2 datetime objects

Tags: c#, .net, datetime

I am trying to get the affected hours between 2 datetime and all i found was a python solution.

For example 'start' is 09:30 and 'end' is 14:00 (same day). The values I'd like returned are

```
[9:00, 10:00, 11:00, 12:00, 13:00, 14:00]
```

[Python get whole hour values between 2 datetime objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6043079/python-get-whole-hour-values-between-2-datetime-objects)

I can't seem to find any equivalent to C#.

Comment: All of the answers so far don't seem to actually answer the question. If you look at the Python question the OP linked to, he doesn't want the COUNT, he wants the list of affected hours.

Comment: im sorry, i tried to edit the question again. Between the 2 datetimes, I want the hours that are involved between the 2 Datetimes, and not the TimeSpan between them

Comment: Are there any assumptions that can be made? Is it always the same day? Or can it be any two arbitrary dates?

Comment: You could write a generator function that returns all hours in a series eternally, then use `TakeWhile`

Comment: Hi Tim, thanks for the follow up. It could be the same day or 2 consecutive dates.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

So you want a list of all hours between both dates? You can use this query:

```
TimeSpan ts =  dt2 - dt1;
IEnumerable<int> hoursBetween = Enumerable.Range(0, (int)ts.TotalHours)
    .Select(i => dt1.AddHours(i).Hour);
```

Sample dates:

```
DateTime dt1 = new DateTime(2013, 07, 08, 15, 50, 00);
DateTime dt2 = new DateTime(2013, 07, 10, 19, 30, 00);
TimeSpan ts =  dt2 - dt1;

IEnumerable<int> hoursBetween = Enumerable.Range(0, (int)ts.TotalHours)
    .Select(i => dt1.AddHours(i).Hour);

foreach (int hour in hoursBetween)
    Console.WriteLine(hour);
```

Output:

```
15
16
17
18
19
20
21
22
23
0
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
11
12
13
14
15
16
17
18
19
20
21
22
23
0
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
11
12
13
14
15
16
17
```

Comment: Doesn't this also include 9 when the dt1 is 09:30?

Comment: @Maarten: Yes, it'll include the current hour. The same as the python code. However, i'm not sure if OP wants all hours or just the hours between one day, so no repeating hours.

Comment: Hi, this is genius way, but how if i need every two hour instead of one ?

Comment: for every two hour , https://stackoverflow.com/q/59259736/4401349 , i asked question =)

Answer (score 3):

The following will return the **total hours between the 2 DateTime objects**:

`(datevalue1 - datevalue2).TotalHours`

And for a custom behavior,such as displaying a list of hours, use a simple custom method on that Timespan created to get a list of hours in your desired format.

**Code suggestion of the top of my head:**

```
public List<String> GenerateHours(DateTime t1,DateTime t2){
    if ((t2-t1).TotalHours >24)){
        //decide what to do.
        return null;
    }else{
        var currentHour = t2.Hour;
        var list = new List<String>();
        for (int i=0;i<(t2-t1).TotalHours;i++){
            if (currentHour<10){
                list.Add("0"+currentHour+":00");
            }else if (currentHour>=10){
                list.Add(currentHour+":00");
            }
            currentHour= (currentHour+1)%24;
        }
        return list;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
TimeSpan ts = DateTime1 - DateTime2;
double totalHours = ts.TotalHours;
```

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timespan.totalhours.aspx): "Gets the value of the current TimeSpan structure expressed in whole and fractional hours."

EDIT: ok, now I see what you're asking for. How about this:

```
var d1 = DateTime.Today.AddHours(9.5);
var d2 = DateTime.Today.AddHours(14);

var first = new DateTime(d1.Year, d1.Month, d1.Day, d1.Minute == 0 ? d1.Hour : d1.Hour + 1, 0, 0);
var second = new DateTime(d2.Year, d2.Month, d2.Day, d2.Minute == 0 ? d2.Hour : d2.Hour + 1, 0, 0);

TimeSpan ts = second - first;

//returns DateTimes affected. I.e., Today at, [10:00, 11:00, 12:00, 13:00, 14:00]
IEnumerable<DateTime> dates = Enumerable.Range(0, (int)ts.TotalHours + 1).Select(hour => first.AddHours(hour));

//Or, if you just want the HOURs
//returns just ints: i.e., DateTimes 10,11,12,13,14
IEnumerable<int> hours = Enumerable.Range(0, (int)ts.TotalHours + 1).Select(hour => first.AddHours(hour).Hour);
```

The first method is needed if you actually have dates that span days. If you DON'T, then the second method that just returns the hours would work fine.

Comment: im sorry, i think this will not work if i am looking for the hours that are involved. I think this will only display the elapsed hours between them

Comment: @superchefliumaohsing. You're right. I edited the answer after you edited your question. :)

Answer (score 2):

```
public IEnumerable<DateTime> GetHoursBetween(DateTime start, DateTime end)
{
    DateTime first = start.Date.AddHours(start.Hour);
    for (DateTime dateTime = first; dateTime <= end; dateTime = dateTime.AddHours(1))
    {
        yield return dateTime;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This should do the trick. Tested in LinqPad.

```
var startDate = new DateTime(2013, 8, 7, 9, 30, 0);
var endDate = new DateTime(2013, 8, 7, 14, 0, 0);

List<string> times = new List<string>();

var currentTime = startDate;
if (currentTime.Minute != 0 || currentTime.Second != 0) {
    // Get next hour
    currentTime = currentTime.AddHours(1).AddMinutes(currentTime.Minute * -1);
}

while (currentTime <= endDate) {
    times.Add(string.Format("{0:00}:00", currentTime.Hour));
    currentTime = currentTime.AddHours(1);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
(int)Math.Abs((date1 - date2).TotalHours)
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply subtract them and get the total of hours from the result. Something like this:

```
var totalHours = (dateTime1 - dateTime2).TotalHours;
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this would work?

```
    public static List<DateTime> GetAffectedHours(DateTime start, DateTime end)
    {
        List<DateTime> result = new List<DateTime>();

        // Strip start of its minutes/seconds/etc
        DateTime initial = new DateTime(start.Year, start.Month, start.Day, start.Hour, 0, 0);

        // Go ahead and get the next hour
        DateTime iterator = initial.AddHours(1.0);

        // if it is still before the end
        while (iterator < end)
        {
            // add it to the results list
            result.Add(iterator);

            // and get the next hour
            iterator = iterator.AddHours(1.0);
        }

        return result;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `For` loop

```
List<int> allHoursBetween = new List<int>();

for (DateTime d = myStartDate; d <= myEndDate; d = d.AddHours(1))
     allHoursBetween.Add(d.Hour);
```