# C# get every two hour between two datetime object

Tags: c#, .net, datetime

I would like to get a list of every two hour between two datetime object

Below is what I have tried for every one hour:

```
TimeSpan betweenTime = EndTime - StartTime; // 15:00PM - 09:00AM 
IEnumerable<int> hoursBetween = Enumerable.Range(0, (int)betweenTime.TotalHours).Select(i => StartTime.AddHours(i).Hour);   

//Output for hoursBetween
9
10
11
12  
13
14

//if between is every two hour
//the expected Output be like
9
11
13
```

Comment: Does the code need to handle 1. daylight savings transitions, and 2. start and end times from different time zones. The answer might get complicated depending on the situations it needs to handle.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use

```
IEnumerable<int> hoursBetween = Enumerable.Range(0, (int)Math.Ceiling(betweenTime.TotalHours / 2)).Select(i => StartTime.AddHours(i * 2).Hour);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can add an additional `where` to only use values that when `mod` by 2 are 0 e.g.:

```
IEnumerable<int> hoursBetween = Enumerable.Range(0, (int)betweenTime.TotalHours).Where(i => i % 2 == 0).Select(i => startTime.AddHours(i).Hour);
```

You can also use a variable in the `Where` clause to handle different steps e.g.

```
var step = 2;
IEnumerable<int> hoursBetween = Enumerable.Range(0, (int)betweenTime.TotalHours).Where(i => i % step == 0).Select(i => startTime.AddHours(i).Hour);
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don’t you make a if function that return the hour when StartTime is higher of 2 hour from the previous time.

I don’t explain well so here is an exemple:

```
int StartTime = //as exemple 15//;
int OldTime = StartTime;
//...

if(StartTime = OldTime + 2) {
    OldTime += 2;
    //do some stuff
}
```

**This is not tested and I am kind of a beginner so let me know if this was useful or not.**