# Get Time in hours between to DateTime variables, but taking not more than 20 hours per date

Tags: c#

The premise is that I want to calculate the hourselapsed between two Datetimes(Start; End). But is not as simple as `TimeSpan ts=end-start; var minutes=ts.TotalHours;` I need to take a maximum of 20 hours out of a single Date. So for example

```
DateTime start = DateTime.Now; //08.09.2021 18:00:00
DateTime end = DateTime.Now.AddDays(3); //08.12.2021 18:00:00
```

The hours for this example would mean that I get the following number of hours:

1. Day 1 = 6 hours
2. Day 2 = 20 hours
3. Day 3 = 20 hours
4. Day 4 = 18 hours

With the Total being 64 hours. What would be the most efficient way to calculate this? Maybe there are specific built in functions that can help with this.

Comment: @ikegami yes I need minutes bet for readability in the example I hours because for smaller more comprehensible numbers. I could find the most efficient ay for hours I could convert to minutes easily.  In this example I can ignore DST

Comment: @ikegami I simplified to using only hours

Comment: I'm not sure what your error is. I get [~72 hours](https://dotnetfiddle.net/28JsDG) for your example code. Why do you think that adding 1 day to a DateTime will have a delta of 6 hours?

Comment: oh, missed "With the Total being 64 hours.". So you want 64 hours in minutes.

Comment: @ikegami at Day 1 it is already 18:00 so there are only 6 hours remaining until midnight, but day for when the time ends it is 18:00 so the 20 hour limit is not reached

Comment: @ikegami I need hours between DT but when calculating not taking more then 20hours per day as in day 2 and 3

Comment: Does this answer your question? [C# get whole hour values between 2 datetime objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17528181/c-sharp-get-whole-hour-values-between-2-datetime-objects)

Comment: Calculate the number of full days in the time period; multiply that by 4 hours; subtract that value from the `TotalHours` value. Also look for any partial days > 20 hours and subtract those hours.

Comment: @gunr2171 unfortunately no. I could do that easily.

Comment: @HereticMonkey Thanks. That was my initial approach but I was wondering if there is a more elegant, quick, efficient way.

Comment: "elegant" is not a measurable, objective quality, which is something Stack Overflow demands of questions. You'd need to post how "quick" and "efficient" your current attempts are if you're looking for something quicker or more efficient.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```cs
private double CalcHours(DateTime start, DateTime end)
{
    if (end < start) { (start, end) = (end, start); }
    if (start.Date == end.Date)
    {
        return Math.Min(20, (end - start).TotalHours);
    }
    return Math.Min(20, (start.Date.AddDays(1) - start).TotalHours)       // First day: start to next midnight, max. 20 hrs
        + ((end.Date - start.Date).TotalDays - 1) * 20                     // Full days with 20 hours between start and end.
        + Math.Min(20, (end - end.Date).TotalHours);                      // Last day: midnight to end, max. 20 hrs
}
```

Comment: This will probably be the final correct answer. I thought that there might be a inline way. Thank you.

Comment: You can use the conditional operator instead of if to check if start and end are the same date, then you have one statement.

Comment: ...but it's complex enough that there is a readability benefit to dividing the whole into statements by using the if statement.