# Get all the times in between two datetime in list

Tags: python, datetime

I want to get all the times in between two datetime. For example i have two datetime

`2016-10-15 12:15:57` and `2016-10-16 12:16:02`

Is there any easiest way to find all the times like below,

```
['2016-10-15 12:15:57','2016-10-15 12:15:58','2016-10-15 12:15:59','2016-10-15 12:16:00','2016-10-15 12:16:01','2016-10-15 12:16:02']
```

Any help would be really appreciated

Comment: You can use a `timedelta` like in this answer - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6043079/python-get-whole-hour-values-between-2-datetime-objects?rq=1

Comment: I think your answer is wrong. Isn't it? You shouldn't have only 5 seconds between a day difference.

Comment: Convert the strings into utc unix time stamps, put it into a for loop with ranges a, b, 1. Then convert the time stamp back into a readable time representation. Accumulate it into an array.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
from datetime import date, datetime, timedelta

def perdelta(start, end, delta):
    curr = start
    while curr <= end:
        yield curr
        curr += delta

dtfmt = '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'

a = '2016-10-15 12:15:57'
b = '2016-10-15 12:16:02'

start = datetime.strptime(a,dtfmt)
end = datetime.strptime(b,dtfmt)

stack=[]
for result in perdelta(start , end, timedelta(seconds=1)):
    stack.append(str(result))

print(stack)
```

**OUTPUT**

> ['2016-10-15 12:15:57', '2016-10-15 12:15:58', '2016-10-15 12:15:59',
>   '2016-10-15 12:16:00', '2016-10-15 12:16:01', '2016-10-15 12:16:02']

Answer (score 0):

This should help you:

```
import datetime

fmt = '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'

a = '2016-10-15 12:15:57'
b = '2016-10-15 12:16:02'

strp_a = datetime.datetime.strptime(a,fmt)
strp_b = datetime.datetime.strptime(b,fmt)

result = []

while strp_a <= strp_b:
    result.append(str(strp_a))
    strp_a += datetime.timedelta(seconds=1)



print(result)
```

Output:

```
['2016-10-15 12:15:57', '2016-10-15 12:15:58', '2016-10-15 12:15:59', 
'2016-10-15 12:16:00', '2016-10-15 12:16:01', '2016-10-15 12:16:02']
```